# Order of query fields in MongoDB using Perl driver

Tags: perl, mongodb, mongodb-indexes

I found an strange behavior in MongoDB::Collection->find function and wanted to ask if this is a result of my misunderstanding of the way the driver works of it it's really an odd behavior.

I want to make a query that searches on the indexed fields but also on some of the other ones. To be sure that MongoDB would use the existing index, I thought of passing the search terms as an array_ref, with the fields in the order I wanted them to be, but the explain() function shows that uses the BasicCursor and scans all documents. If, on the other side, I pass the search terms as a hash_ref (which doesn't ensure and field order), MongoDB gets the fields in the correct order and uses the existing index.

I have a collection with documents as follow:

```
{
    "customer" : NumberLong(),
    "date" : ISODate(),
    field_a : 1,
    field_b: 2,
    [...]
    field_n: 1
}
```

There is an index called `customer_1_date_1` on fields customer and date.

When I give the search terms as an array ref, the explain command states:

```
my $SearchTerms = [
    'customer', $customer, 
    'date'    , $date    , 
    'field_a' , $field_a , 
    'field_b' , $field_b , 
];

cursor                    "BasicCursor",
[...]
nscanned                  5802,
nscannedAllPlans          5802,
[...]
```

On the other side, when I give the search terms as a hash ref, the explain command states:

```
my $SearchTerms = {
    customer => $customer,
    date     => $date,
    field_a  => $field_a,
    field_b  => $field_b,
};

allPlans                  [
    [0] {
        cursor            "BtreeCursor customer_1_date_1",
        [...]
        n                 1,
        nscanned          4,
        nscannedObjects   4
    },
    [1] {
        cursor            "BasicCursor",
        [...]
        n                 0,
        nscanned          4,
        nscannedObjects   4
    }
],
[...]
nscanned                  4,
nscannedAllPlans          8,
nscannedObjects           4,
nscannedObjectsAllPlans   8,
```

So, my question is: should I trust the hash ref to always get the existing index? 
Is there any way, without using additional modules, to ensure this?

Thank you all,

Juanma

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Perl, but there must be something else going on here. The order of the fields in the query does not matter for index selection. I'm guessing the semantics of find with an array are different. I'm surprised it works at all. Can you log what the query that gets sent to MongoDB is? I bet seeing the two queries next to each other will clear up the confusion.

Comment: Hi, @wdberkeley, I'm not sure I follow. The query is just that SearchTerms variable. I do $MyCollection->find($SearchTerms). The documentation just states: `$query can be a hash reference, Tie::IxHash, or array reference (with an even number of elements)`, being `Tie::IxHash` a module that offers a hash with the keys in the order you want them.